mac app use AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer changes the audio stream sampling rate. Prompt error "insz"
I want to modify the sampling rate of the audio stream I get from the virtual device. In order to output to the selected USB audio device.
The following code works when the sample rate of the output oFormat is the same as that of the input iFormat.
However, when the sample rate is different, an "insz" error is displayed
The code is as follows
- (void)setFormat:(AudioStreamBasicDescription)inputFormat output:(AudioStreamBasicDescription)outputFormat{
    oFormat = outputFormat;
    iFormat = inputFormat;
/*
(AudioStreamBasicDescription) oFormat = {
  mSampleRate = 192000
  mFormatID = 1819304813
  mFormatFlags = 41
  mBytesPerPacket = 4
  mFramesPerPacket = 1
  mBytesPerFrame = 4
  mChannelsPerFrame = 2
  mBitsPerChannel = 32
  mReserved = 0
}
(AudioStreamBasicDescription) iFormat = {
  mSampleRate = 96000
  mFormatID = 1819304813
  mFormatFlags = 41
  mBytesPerPacket = 4
  mFramesPerPacket = 1
  mBytesPerFrame = 4
  mChannelsPerFrame = 2
  mBitsPerChannel = 32
  mReserved = 0
}
**/
    OSStatus status = AudioConverterNew(&inputFormat,
                                        &oFormat,
                                        &audioConverter);
    CheckResult(status, "AudioConveterNew failed");
}

- (AudioBufferList *)convertDataFromAudioBufferList:(AudioBufferList *)audioBufferList
                    withNumberOfFrames:(UInt32)frames{

    UInt32 packetsPerBuffer = 0;
    UInt32 outputBufferSize = 128 * 32;
    UInt32 sizePerPacket = iFormat.mBytesPerPacket;
    if (sizePerPacket == 0) {
        UInt32 size = sizeof(sizePerPacket);
        OSStatus status = AudioConverterGetProperty(audioConverter,
                                           kAudioConverterPropertyMaximumOutputPacketSize,
                                           &size,
                                           &sizePerPacket);
        CheckResult(status, "Couldn't get kAudioConverterPropertyMaximumOutputPacketSize");
        if (sizePerPacket > outputBufferSize)
            outputBufferSize = sizePerPacket;
        packetsPerBuffer = outputBufferSize / sizePerPacket;
        _aspd = (AudioStreamPacketDescription *)malloc(sizeof(AudioStreamPacketDescription) * packetsPerBuffer);
    } else {
        packetsPerBuffer = outputBufferSize / sizePerPacket;
    }


    AudioBufferList *floatAudioBufferList = [self audioBufferListWithNumberOfFrames:frames numberOfChannels:oFormat.mChannelsPerFrame interleaved:false];

    OSStatus status = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(audioConverter,
                                                      MyAudioConverterCallback,
                                                      audioBufferList,
                                                      &frames,
                                                      floatAudioBufferList,
                                                      nil);
    CheckResult(status, "AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer");
    if (status > 0 ) {
        AudioConverterReset(audioConverter);
    }
    if (_aspd) {
        free(_aspd);
    }
    return  floatAudioBufferList;
}
- (AudioBufferList *)audioBufferListWithNumberOfFrames:(UInt32)frames
                                      numberOfChannels:(UInt32)channels
                                           interleaved:(BOOL)interleaved
{
    unsigned nBuffers;
    unsigned bufferSize;
    unsigned channelsPerBuffer;
    if (interleaved)
    {
        nBuffers = 1;
        bufferSize = sizeof(float) * frames * channels;
        channelsPerBuffer = channels;
    }
    else
    {
        nBuffers = channels;
        bufferSize = sizeof(float) * frames;
        channelsPerBuffer = 1;
    }
    
    AudioBufferList *audioBufferList = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + sizeof(AudioBuffer) * (channels-1));
    audioBufferList->mNumberBuffers = nBuffers;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < nBuffers; i++)
    {
        audioBufferList->mBuffers[i].mNumberChannels = channelsPerBuffer;
        audioBufferList->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = bufferSize;
        audioBufferList->mBuffers[i].mData = calloc(bufferSize, 1);
    }
    return audioBufferList;
}

How to modify tell me
